# oracle data type = number, how does exponent relate to precision and scale?

Tags: database, oracle

I've been trying to understand Oracle database's use of data type = number. I ran across the following link:

[ask tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1619552483055)

and I'm having trouble interpreting it. I should mention I don't have Oracle background, but approaching this from Matlab experience. I understand number data type has a precision and scale. What I don't understand is how the exponent is treated here. Is the exponent a separate consideration from precision and scale? Or, is the exponent limited by precision and scale?

Here's my confusion -- the above link starts with:

Q: I declared the datatype of a column of a table as NUMBER & Presumed it to 
   be Number(38) to be specific. But What I found to be strange that, it is 
   accepting digits beyong 38 digits.ie. 1.111E+125. If the Datatype's precision 
   is 38 and scale can range from -84 to 127 how this value can insert into the column.

A: and we said...
   1.111e+125 only has 4 digits of precision (number of digits needed to represent 
   the number -- in this case 1111).

Which seems to indicate the exponent is treated separate from precision and scale. But a few messages down someone else asks:

Q: When I create a table like:
   create table test(no number(7)) ;
   insert into test values(1.00e+25) ;
   it gives the following error message:
       ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allows for this column.
   Can u pls. explain this.

A: you said 7 digits, you gave it 25

which seems to indicate the exponent is limited by the precision. Hoping someone can help me understand how both answers can be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`number(7)` is an integer with (at most) seven digits (in the "normal" decimal representation).  Note that fractions are not allowed. Numbers larger than 9,999,999 will not be accepted. This has nothing to do with how many significant digits they have. This is a "business constraint" put in place by you.

`number(7,2)` would be a number with seven digits, including two after the decimal point

`number` is a floating point number with 38 digits of precision (i.e. 38 significant digits, no matter where they are in relation to the decimal point). The exponent can be anything between -84 and 125. There are no "business contraints" here. You can store as much as Oracle can store (which is 38 digits and the exponent between -84 and 125).

Note that all these numbers are stored as decimal data (to avoid rounding errors when converting into binary), so "digits" really mean decimal digits (not binary bits).

Comment: Thanks Thilo, Let me see... NUMBER and NUMBER(38) are really two completely different animals. While they both have 38 decimal digits of precision, the NUMBER includes exponents such that it can store much larger and smaller values, whereas NUMBER(38) is limited to a number containing 38 decimal digits (regardless of where decimal point is placed). Is that right?

Comment: NUMBER(38) would be an integer between +1E+38 and -1E+38. 38 digits right in front of the decimal point.

Comment: OK, I guess what I was getting at is once you enter a precision into the NUMBER data type, you essentially are limiting the exponent such that the NUMBER(d) (where d is an integer) can only store +1E+38 to -1E+38. NUMBER without a precision or scale specified can store a much larger or smaller value.

Comment: True. NUMBER can store much larger values than NUMBER(d) or NUMBER(d,p), but it is a floating point value whereas the other are fixed point. So even within the huge range for NUMBER you also only have a limited (38 digits) precision. "Longer" numbers will be rounded.